# Query String is Breaking SSL?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, query-string

I have a page that forces SSL and everything checks out fine in my browser without any query strings. I added some query strings in order to query the database for a particular product that we offer and now Google Chrome says "Your connection is encrypted with 256-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure." Is this something to worry about? Is Chrome only weary of the query strings?

Comment: Have a look at the page information in Chrome.  It should tell you  which assets loaded with the page are not loaded via SSL.  Then work from there.  Most likely it's an image or some content from a CDN (if you're using one).

Comment: Removed the image from the CDN -- fixed the issue. Thanks Aleks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your query string opens a page that presents images or content not hosted within the domain (s) listed in the SSL Certificate, then Chrome is simply warning you that some of the content on the page is not encrypted over SSL because it s being retrieved from an unencrypted source.

**Basically, if your content page includes content from another source (ie. Inline Frame, Image, YouTube video, etc), the page content is not completely secure.**

Comment: Ah. It's pulling in an image from a CDN. Guess I'll have to remove the image to maintain security. Thanks Chris.